# Why is the Giant Hothead/Flashwing not working?

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-giants

The Giant Hothead seems to not be working - do you have any ideas on whas is causing the failure, and what we can do to fix it? We also have a Flashwing that wont work - again, do you happen to know how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do they fail to connect? Do you get any sort of error message? What system are you playing on? Give us as much information as you can, and it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, the physical figures have problems.  There's not really anything to be done except return/exchange them, or buy new ones if they're outside of the return window.  My brother had one that didn't work right out of the package, and he had to return it for a refund.  It's not specific to certain figures; any of them can fail without warning as far as I know, although it's not common at all.